# Float left menu, where am I wrong?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I am working on a 960 px-design at the moment, and I am trying to do a menu in  where it is supposed to be 6 "buttons" with a 5 px margin between each one. I know how to do this, and I cannot seem to find what is wrong with my code. It would be very helpful if someone could look through my code with some fresh eyes and tell me where the issue is...

http://jsfiddle.net/9tx8v/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> ----- </title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>ASDER</header>

            <nav>
                <div id="ett"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
                <div id="två"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
                <div id="tre"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
                <div id="fyra"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
                <div id="fem"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
                <div id="sex"> <img src="menu.jpg"/>
            </nav>

            <article class="art-1">   </article>

            <footer> - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
}

article {
    width: 462px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#ett, #två, #tre, #fyra, #fem, #sex {
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Sorry for include a shitload of unnecessary code, but I'm so fed up atm I might just include the whole thing...

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are <div> not closed and not being <a> ?

Comment: Are the images in the nav div elements important to the code? Because you did not include them in the fiddle resource. Also, are you trying to accomplish a vertical menu? or a horizontal menu?

Comment: @bboysupaman I wouldn't say. And I'm trying to do a horizontal one

Comment: @GCyrillus Not being <a>? And the divs are closed?

Comment: maybe the copy/paste didn't work in your jsfiddle , in a <nav> i would expect to see links :) not just <div><img/> , cheers  ...  see every one tells you about unclosed <div> :)

Comment: I'm a fkking idiot... didn't realise i only closed the IMG tags and not the DIV's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all as a better practice keep the closing tags for `</div>` elements.

```
<div id="ett"> <img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
<div id="två"> <img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
...
```

Then just float each element you don't need to float the `nav`:

```
#ett, #två, #tre, #fyra, #fem, #sex {
  width:130px;
  height:60px;
  margin-left:5px;
  float:left; /* Add this*/
}
```

Check this [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tx8v/1/)

Comment: Didn't realise I only closed the IMG tags and not the DIVs... thanks!

Comment: np mate glad to help @user3236461 don't forget that wasn't the only error you need to float each element. If this was helpfull and since was the first answer don't forget to mark it as the final answer :)

Comment: arf ! , a nav without links, hope you are going to tell us they exist in your real page :)

Answer (score 2):

How about closing your DIV's? And you need a `float:left` for any DIV

*HTML*

```
<nav>
    <div id="ett">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="två">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="tre">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="fyra">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="fem">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="sex">
        <img src="menu.jpg" />
    </div>
</nav>
```

*CSS*

```
nav div {
    float:left;
    width:130px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: if <a> are used , no need to float them :) , actually, they are badly missing for navbar :)

Comment: Didn't realise I only closed the IMG tags and not the DIVs... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, close your divs:

```
<div id="två"><img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
<div id="tre"><img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
<div id="fyra"><img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
<div id="fem"><img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
<div id="sex"><img src="menu.jpg"/></div>
```

Add float: left in you css:

```
#ett, #två, #tre, #fyra, #fem, #sex {
    width:130px;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Didn't realise I only closed the IMG tags and not the DIVs... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<nav>` should contains `<a>` , else it is not a `<nav>`.
Do not forget to close your tags and adapt their display if needed on a row , sized or on top of each others :)